# Summing when values within a group is distinct in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

When B_Allocation value for a Manager is not distinct, I want to sum the distinct value. For example for Manager 5, I want to be able to sum 10800, 661782.60, 2141987.20 and 2163743.43. For Managers like 6, 8 and 14 whose B_Allocation are not distinct, I want the values as they appear below ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZ5y.png))

```
select
          BU.BuCode
        , PE.ManagerID
        , BUA.AllocatedAmount as B_Allocation
        , PE.AllocatedAmount
    from CFMS_ProjectEntry PE
    join CFMS_BUAllocation BUA on BUA.BUDGETENTRYID = PE.BUDGETENTRYID
    join CFMS_BU           BU  on BU.BUID           = BUA.BUID
    join CFMS_User         US  on US.UserID         = PE.ManagerID
    where BUCODE = 42406016
    group by  BU.BUCode
            , ManagerID
            , BUA.AllocatedAmount
            , PE.AllocatedAmount
```

What I want ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqhwF.png)):

```
+ -------- + --------- + ------------ + --------------- +
| BUCode   | ManagerID | B_Allocation | AllocatedAmount |
+ -------- + --------- + ------------ + --------------- +
| 42406016 | 5         | 10800.00     | 1293916.30      |
| 42406016 | 5         | 661782.60    | 1723699.70      |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2141987.20   | 4628466.40      |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2163743.43   | 109956.12       |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2163743.43   | 407655.00       |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2163743.43   | 499902.00       |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2163743.43   | 523275.55       |
| 42406016 | 5         | 2163743.43   | 622954.76       |
| 42406016 | 6         | 4747880.45   | 1500000.00      |
| 42406016 | 6         | 4747880.45   | 2000000.00      |
| 42406016 | 8         | 726893.75    | 14142.71        |
| 42406016 | 8         | 726893.75    | 22143.56        |
| 42406016 | 8         | 726893.75    | 106448.50       |
| 42406016 | 8         | 726893.75    | 265501.45       |
| 42406016 | 8         | 726893.75    | 318657.53       |
| 42406016 | 14        | 4747880.45   | 747880.45       |
+ -------- + --------- + ------------ + --------------- +
```

Comment: You should first remove the duplicates since you dont want these right? By adding a distinct to your query, although you would need to remove the AllocatedAmount for this to work. You could then use the Sum() for the B_Allocation. You might also need to group by ManagerID for sum to work. Try it and please write your sql in the question.

    select distinct BU.BUCode, PE.ManagerID,sum(BUA.AllocatedAmount) as B_Allocation

Comment: @RPG, Please provide the table structure of all tables involved, INSERT scripts for the values and what query you tried and what result you got. What are you expecting as an end result. Please always try to provide in text format. It will be easy for people to get values from text and help you as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @T1 Table(BUCode INT, ManagerID INT, B_Allocation Float,     AllocatedAmount Float);
Declare @T2 Table(BUCode INT, ManagerID INT, B_Allocation Float,     AllocatedAmount Float);
with cte as (**Add your Select statement here**)

Insert Into @T1
Select * from cte 

Insert Into @T2
Select BUCode, ManagerID, sum(B_Allocation) from @T1
Group By BUCode, ManagerID

Select t2.BUCode, t2.ManagerID, t2.B_Allocation, t1.AllocatedAmount   from @T1 as t1
left join @T2 as t2 on t1.BUCode = t2.BUCode AND t1.ManagerID = t2.ManagerID
```